# Query MySQL from Oracle requires quotes around field names

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

We have a project which requires us to query a MySQL database from Oracle. The database instances reside on separate Linux servers.

The issue the developers are having is age old, they are required to use double quotes around field names.

The MySQL database was created using lower case table and field names. Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS web_access_log (
  ip_address varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  request varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  last_request_date datetime NOT NULL,
  count_last_date int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  total_hits int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  burst_start_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY index1 (last_request_date),
  KEY ip_address (ip_address,request(255),last_request_date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Recently, I added the `lower_case_table_names` to /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf setting it to a value of "1"

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Information regarding the Oracle side:

The driver used to connect to MySQL is the unixODBC driver from /etc/odbcinst.ini

[image]

The MySQL ODBC Settings from /etc/odbc.ini

[image]

So when they query MySQL from the unixODBC command line, isql, and issue a simple `select userid from web_user_group` everything seems to work just fine.

However, if they connect though the Oracle PL/SQL command line they receive an error **"USERID": invalid indentifer**.

Finally, from the PL/SQL command line if they place quotes around the field name `select "userid" from web_user_group` then the query works.

I understand that most Linux flavors are case sensitive,

> Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case-sensitive in Windows, but are case-sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

[Taken from MySQL documentation 9.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

So is this something controlled by the driver, or a "feature" of Oracle and the developers have to live with it?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718999/4215616) answer from SO as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572872/4215616) answer to a similar question on SO.

However, these answers leads me to believe this is specific to Oracle. But does it apply when querying an external database from Oracle?

Comment: Good question but probably belongs here https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @T.S.Thanks for the advice. I'm just so used to coming here, I forget the other sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This MariaDB document](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) has some notes about ODBC case sensitivity:

> For instance, Oracle follows to the SQL standard here. It converts non-quoted identifiers to upper case. This is correct and expected. PostgreSQL is not standard. It converts identifiers to lower case. MySQL/MariaDB is not standard. They preserve identifiers on Linux, and convert to lower case on Windows.

However, the MySQL documentation you linked says:

> **Column**, index, stored routine, event, and resource group **names are not case-sensitive on any platform**, nor are column aliases.

Since your issue is with the column name "userid" being case-sensitive, I think the issue is probably with the MySQL ODBC driver, since it sounds like it's not normal MySQL behavior.

You might try upgrading your myodbc connector (ie, driver library) from version 5 to version 8, but I don't know if that'll help or not - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll take a look

Comment: the developers have updated the MySQL ODBC driver, but that has not helped the issue. Thank you, again, for the suggestion